# многомерный массив со связями "каждый к каждому"

Tags: php, массивы

есть многомерный массив вида

```
[­["14","16"],["26"],["24"],["5","8"]]
```

длина общего массива не ограничена,вложенные будут в среднем 1-3 элемента,хотя по факту тоже не ограничено.
вложенные всегда будут числами, не массивами, т.е. массив двумерный.
задача получить связь "каждый с каждым", т.е. я должен получить наборы вида

```
14,26,24,5
14,26,24,8
16,26,24,5
16,26,24,8;
```

я и циклы гонял, и рекурсию пробовал, что-то всё хрень выходит. чую, что я просто уже мозгом потёк, а решение элементарное.

Comment: Расшифруйте тип связи "Каждый с каждым", а то чую уже у меня мозг течет). Вы хотите получить все возможные варианты выборки из массива?

Comment: смотрите на стековерфлоу 'php permutation' куча решений

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование массива php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763397/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-php)

Answer (score 0):

что-то я вчера перегрелся
вот простое и понятное решение: сначала результат это массив в котором лежит один пустой массив - массив перестановок пустого массива, потом берем первый массив из входных данных и добавляем его в конец каждого элемента в том что сейчас в результате

```
<?php

function combine($data)
{
    $res = [[]];
    while ($data) {
        $firstData = array_shift($data);
        $newRes = [];
        foreach ($res as $resEl) {
            foreach($firstData as $dataEl) {
                $newRes[] = array_merge($resEl, [$dataEl]);
            }
        }
        $res = $newRes;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

в работе [песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e7df96c6208e59f4d5a3de76157502d03acd347)

```
$data = [["14","16"],["26"],["24"],["5","8"]];

foreach (combine($data) as $arr) {
    echo implode($arr, ' ') . "\n";
}

//output:
14 26 24 5
14 26 24 8
16 26 24 5
16 26 24 8
```