# Скомбинировать данные из одного массива в несколько

Tags: php, массивы

Не силен в логических вычислениях, и не очень понимаю работу php генераторов, поэтому прошу помочь с одним вопросом.
Есть массив:

```
$arrayName = array(
  '0' => '1X',
  '1' => '1',
  '2' => '1',
  '3' => '1',
  '4' => '1',
  '5' => '1',
  '6' => '1',
  '7' => '1',
  '8' => '1',
  '9' => '1',
  '10' => '1',
  '11' => '1',
  '12' => '1',
  '13' => '1',
  '14' => '1',
);
```

Из этого массива получается 2 варианта массивов:

И РАЗ

```
$arrayName = array(
  '0' => '1',
  '1' => '1',
  '2' => '1',
  '3' => '1',
  '4' => '1',
  '5' => '1',
  '6' => '1',
  '7' => '1',
  '8' => '1',
  '9' => '1',
  '10' => '1',
  '11' => '1',
  '12' => '1',
  '13' => '1',
  '14' => '1',
);
```

И ДВА

```
$arrayName = array(
  '0' => 'X',
  '1' => '1',
  '2' => '1',
  '3' => '1',
  '4' => '1',
  '5' => '1',
  '6' => '1',
  '7' => '1',
  '8' => '1',
  '9' => '1',
  '10' => '1',
  '11' => '1',
  '12' => '1',
  '13' => '1',
  '14' => '1',
);
```

Это было несложно. То есть ключ номер 0 необходимо разбить по 1 символу, ну предположим функцией str_split и сгенерировать все возможные варианты. В данном примере всего 2 варианта а вот в таком массиве

```
$arrayName = array(
  '0' => '1X',
  '1' => '1X2',
  '2' => '1X2',
  '3' => '1',
  '4' => '1',
  '5' => '1',
  '6' => '1',
  '7' => '1',
  '8' => '1',
  '9' => '1',
  '10' => '1',
  '11' => '1',
  '12' => '1',
  '13' => '1',
  '14' => '1X2',
);
```

вариантов будет 54 и все их необходимо сгенерировать так, чтобы не было одинаковых массивов.

Количество вариантов в массиве я считаю так

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
  $count = str_split($value);
  $i = $i*count($count);
}
echo $i;
```

Подскажите может куда капнуть, может все проще чем кажется...

Спасибо!

Comment: циклами, циклами

Comment: Рекурсивная функция

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование массива php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763397/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
<?php
$arrayName = array(
    '0' => '1X',
    '1' => '1X2',
    '13' => '1',
    '14' => 'X2'
);

function array_rec($array)
{
    global $arrayout;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $count = strlen($value);
        if ($count > 1)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
            {
                $array2       = $array;
                $array2[$key] = $value[$i];
                array_rec($array2);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    $arrayout[] = $array;
    return;
}

$arrayout = array();
array_rec($arrayName);
print_r($arrayout);
```

Результат (пример я сократил, чтобы не сильно большой вывод был):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => X
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => X
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => X
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => X
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => 2
        [13] => 1
        [14] => X
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => X
        [1] => 2
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 2
    )

)
```

Comment: Это работает! Огромное спасибо!!!